# How to save JavaScript generated content as HTML in the file?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table with 1 row, 11 columns. Now I generated the following JavaScript code to add a new row using a Button.
The issue is, when i refresh the page, the new rows that i added using this javascript, are lost. I want them to be saved permanently in the HTML file. How can this be done?

```
<script>
function AddNewRow()
{
    var table = document.getElementById("table1");
    var row = table.insertRow(1);

    var cell0 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(1);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(2);
    var cell3 = row.insertCell(3);
    var cell4 = row.insertCell(4);
    var cell5 = row.insertCell(5);
    var cell6 = row.insertCell(6);
    var cell7 = row.insertCell(7);
    var cell8 = row.insertCell(8);
    var cell9 = row.insertCell(9);
    var cell10 = row.insertCell(10);
</script>
```

Comment: You want to save the rows *permanently* in the HTML file? You'd need to do that server side. Not really sure what exactly you're trying to accomplish here.

Comment: Are you using a server side language like PHP?

Comment: Not using serverside. See, what i am asking is.
At first - [link](http://snag.gy/WbxWj.jpg).

Then, I add a new row as [link](http://snag.gy/fsHBB.jpg).
Now when I refresh, there is no new row. Just same old one row.
So, i want to save this new row in the HTML file.

Comment: In that case, you could use a cookie (http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp) or HTML5 Web Storage (http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp). You need to give us more information on your environment, and the requirements of your project.

Comment: I had to make a stackoverflow account for this. I am terribly stuck at this Automation of Estimation(FPA) application which i am supposed to submit day after tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

The HTML file remains on a server inaccessible to the client, but it would be perfectly possible for the browser to save the added information - either in HTML form, or as a more storage-focused format like XML/JSON. It would then need to be loaded back into Javascript and re-added to the page each time your page starts up.

Read up on the localStorage documentation at Mozilla - they could give you a general idea of storing/loading. With the innerHTML readable/writable property, hopefully you have an idea of how you could accomplish this.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage#localStorage